# Lie subalgebras of $so(3)$ and complex Lie subalgebras of $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for a reference that:
describes all Lie subalgebras of $so(3)$,and describes all complex Lie subalgebras of $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Does someone have appropriate references?

Comment: the complex Lie algebras (2,ℂ): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_Lie_algebra#Representation_theory_of_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000007-QINU%60%22'%7F

Comment: Lie algebras $su(2)$ and $so(3)$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it answers these specific questions explicitly, but you can find all you need in Helgason's book *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces.*